# There exists $k_0$ such that there are no simple group of order $p^kn$ for $k \geq k_0$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, simple-groups

**Problem:**
Let $p$ be a prime and $n$ such that $\gcd(n,p)=1$. Then there exists $k_0$ such that for all $k \geq k_0$ any group of order $p^kn$ is not simple.

**Attempt:**
I tried using the $p$-Sylow. Let us define $n_p$ the number of $p$-Sylow. Then we have that $n_p $ divide $n$ and that $n_p=1+hp$ for some $h \geq 1$.
The cardinality of elements of order $p^a$ is more than $p^{k-1}(p-1)n_p + p^{k-1} \geq p^{k+1}$ but this does not help.

**Trivial remark:** If $n$ is a prime and $n<p$ then the $p$-Sylow is normal.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: It follows directly from [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4132659/proving-that-group-is-not-simple-using-sylows-theorems?rq=1).